# How can I retrieve the userid used to execute sudo command via ssh without a tty

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, ksh, sudo

Without having a tty, whats the best way to get back the userid that authenticated to the system via ssh and executed the following commands (as examples).

tty's technically aren't possible as these commands will be executed via pssh and automated across many systems.

```
>ssh -q node1 "sudo su - idm -c 'who am i'"
>ssh -q node1 "sudo su - idm -c 'echo hello'"
hello
>ssh -q node1"sudo su - idm -c 'logname'"
logname: no login name
```

Comment: I was able to execute various command from ssh in a simpler scenario, e.g. `ssh tharrison@myremotenode "whoami"`.  `logname` also worked, but `who am i` did not.  Please edit your answer to include information about the nature of the user `idm` -- when you are logged into the terminal on `node1` what is your output?

Comment: the issue isn't that the commands don't work, since they obviously do.. 
What I'm trying to ascertain is the ID of the user that 'logged' into the system and executed the original sudo su -  from within the command executed.

Comment: Yes, of course the commands work in the context of your terminal session.  But a tty and a remote session are very different in terms of environment -- for example, perhaps some of the commands depend upon a tty to work, which you don't have in a remote session.  `sudo` also adds a wrinkle.  There's not enough information in your question about context to provide an authoritative answer, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but there is a way to catch the username before actually executing the intended command, like this: `ssh -q node1 'sudo su - idm -c "echo $USER"'`

The USER variable will contain the user used to connect to the "node1" since it's initialized during login, with or without a tty. The variable will be replaced after ssh is running and before sudo command is started.
The used quotes are important since the variable should not be replaced before the ssh is actually launched.
This is not usefull in case you would want to launch the command from inside a script, unless you provide the $USER as argument to that script and then use it internally from the argument list.

Another possibility is using the Parent PID , another variable available that can be found by climbing back on the process tree:
`ssh -q node1 'sudo su - idm -c "ps -hp $PPID -o user"'` will display you the "sshuser".

Or from inside the script (not so nice but it works):

```
# cat ~idm/test.sh
#!/bin/bash -x
SSHUSER=$(ps -hp $(ps -hp $(ps -hp $PPID -o ppid) -o ppid) -o user)
echo $SSHUSER
```

Execute with:

```
# ssh node1 'sudo su - idm -c "./test.sh"'
sshuser
```

There are 3 "ps" commands because the parent of the script is the "su", the parent of the "su" is the "sudo" and finally the parent of "sudo" is holding the username you need.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start out by saying that I can't seem to duplicate your issue.

```
$ ssh -T pc "sudo su - ghoti2 -c 'whoami'"
ghoti2
$ ssh -T pc "sudo su - ghoti2 -c 'logname'"
ghoti
```

The `-T` option should be disabling the allocation of a tty, yet `logname` still functions. This may be a subtle different in the operating systems we're running. I use FreeBSD. You haven't mentioned what you're using.

That said, if the problem is that your login use is being hidden by `sudo`, you might want to look ad adjusting your `sudo` configuration and usage.

For example, the following sudo configuration makes the login user visible to the command being run:

```
    Defaults>root          !set_logname
```

The documentation for this option, from `man sudoers`, states:

> ```
>    set_logname     Normally, sudo will set the LOGNAME, USER and USERNAME
>                    environment variables to the name of the target user
>                    (usually root unless the -u option is given).  However,
>                    since some programs (including the RCS revision control
>                    system) use LOGNAME to determine the real identity of
>                    the user, it may be desirable to change this behavior.
>                    This can be done by negating the set_logname option.
>                    Note that if the env_reset option has not been
>                    disabled, entries in the env_keep list will override
>                    the value of set_logname.  This flag is on by default.
> ```

Note that regardless of whether this is set, you negate the usefulness of this when you mis-use `sudo` by using it to launch `su`.  Even with this option disabled in my sudo configuration, I get the following:

```
$ ssh -T pc sudo su - ghoti2 -c env
TERM=su
BLOCKSIZE=K
MAIL=/var/mail/ghoti2
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/ghoti2/bin
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
HOME=/home/ghoti2
USER=ghoti2
HOSTTYPE=FreeBSD
VENDOR=amd
OSTYPE=FreeBSD
MACHTYPE=x86_64
SHLVL=1
PWD=/home/ghoti2
LOGNAME=ghoti2
GROUP=unknown
HOST=pc
```

In this case, while sudo may be leaving the LOGNAME, USER and USERNAME variables, they are being overwritten by the `su -`.

But if I use `sudo` options correctly, I can also do this:

```
$ ssh pc sudo -u ghoti2 env
PATH=/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/ghoti/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games
TERM=su
LC_COLLATE=C
SHELL=/bin/tcsh
LOGNAME=ghoti2
USER=ghoti2
USERNAME=ghoti2
MAIL=/var/mail/ghoti2
HOME=/home/ghoti2
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
SUDO_USER=ghoti
SUDO_UID=1001
SUDO_GID=1001
```

**Note the `$SUDO_USER` variable.** It is provided as part of the environment to anything that sudo runs. Of course, in your usage, it's not available, because you eliminate this part of the environment by running `su -`.  (You should `man su` for details about this.)

---

Alternately, if improving your sudo use isn't an option, what about providing the logged-in user as an argument to whatever is being run via sudo?

```
$ ssh node1 "sudo su - idm -c '/path/to/script $USER'"
```

This would include the `$USER` variable as expanded by the client side of the connection. Alternately, by reversing the quotes:

```
$ ssh node1 'sudo su - idm -c "/path/to/script $USER"'
```

you could make sure that `$USER` is expanded on the remote end.

Then, from within `script`, the variable `$1` would be the username that authenticated using sudo.